# Can a single comma close off two asides?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, appositives

Example:

*The text's references to Joyce, as well as to Hemingway, who would often fight other pub-goers on behalf of the Irishman, made no mistake about this.*

It seems fine to me, but I just remember reading that commas should always come in pairs in these cases, so was wondering if there was anything I should be aware of or if the commas can share duties as they do here. I don't see any other solution besides rewording or setting off the larger bit in dashes or something, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: There are two nested parentheticals. <<  The text's references to Joyce (as well as to Hemingway [who would often fight other pub-goers on behalf of the Irishman]) made no mistake about this >> But this looks clumsy. The original is clear enough, but a compromise is << The text's references to Joyce, as well as to Hemingway (who would often fight other pub-goers on behalf of the Irishman), made no mistake about this. >>

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it would seem to me that it is the first and third commas which are parenthetical.

The one in the middle is performing a different function, namely of separating the main part of the subordinate clause, from its own relative clause.